# How can I prove that each component of a 2-regular graph is a cycle?

Tags: graph-theory

I tried to look at the similar questions asked before, however, they all assume that if a graph is simply one vertex then that also constitutes a cycle which is an assumption I'm not allowed to make. I did a lot of cases and my question statement turned out to be true in each case, however I don't know how to show that each and every component is a cycle?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Notice something reversed - if a graph is s.t. all it's components are cycles, then it's 2-regular. Maybe that helps.

Comment: what does s.t mean?

Comment: It means "such that"

Comment: "s.t." doesn't mean anything, but some bad people use it as an abbreviation for "such that".

Comment: If you're talking about *simple* graphs, then a graph with just one vertex is not $2$-regular, so how is that a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with a vertex $v_1$. It has degree $2$, so let $v_2$ be one of the vertices adjacent to $v_1$. The degree of $v_2$ is $2$, so it is adjacent to $v_1$ and one other vertex; call that other vertex $v_3$. Keep going, constructing a path $v_1,v_2,v_3,\ldots\;$. The graph is finite, so at some point you’ll run out of unused vertices and have a path $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n$ such that the vertices adjacent to $v_n$ are $v_{n-1}$ and one of the other vertices in the path. That vertex cannot be any of the vertices $v_2,v_3,\ldots,v_{n-2}$: if $2\le k\le n-2$, $v_k$ is adjacent to $v_{k-1}$ and $v_{k+1}$, and $\deg(v_k)=2$, so $v_k$ isn’t adjacent to any other vertex. The only possibility is $v_1$: $v_n$ must be adjacent to $v_1$, and we have a cycle.

The regularity hypothesis clearly implies that there are no edges from this cycle to any other vertex, so this cycle must be a component of the graph. If you set up the proof as an induction on the number of components in the graph, this argument covers both the base case of a connected graph and the induction step, since it reduces the number of potentially non-cyclic components by $1$.

Comment: when you say 'That vertex cannot be any of the vertices', what vertex are u referring to? V_k?

Comment: @new_hello_world: ‘That vertex’ clearly refers to ‘one of the other vertices in the path’ in the previous sentence, i.e., to the vertex other than $v_{n-1}$ that is adjacent to $v_n$. There really isn’t any specific $v_k$ mentioned anywhere; $k$ is just an index used to make it easy to talk about all of the vertices $v_2,\ldots,v_{n-2}$ at once.